# Why am I getting SQL syntax error in custom PHP code?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to build an update query but I keep getting the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='Damien', `last_name`='Surname', where `id`='49'' at line 2

My PHP is as follows:

```
if($get['cmd'] == 'sname')
{
mysql_query("update users 
`first_name`='$get[first_name]', 
`last_name`='$get[last_name]',
where `id`='$get[id]'") or die(mysql_error());
//header("Location: $ret"); 
echo "changes done";
exit();
}
```

and HTML as follows

```
<input name="doSave" type="button" id="doSave" value="Save" onclick='$.get("dos.php",{ cmd: "sname",first_name:$("input#first_name").val(),last_name:$("input#last_name").val(),id: "<?php echo $row_settings['id']; ?>" } ,function(data){ $("#msg").html(data); });'>
```

Can anyone see what's wrong in my code that will be giving me this error?

Comment: Nice [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com)... enjoy having your server pw3nd.

Comment: @Marc B - How does that comment help me?

Comment: Would you mind giving me an idea of stopping this then? Do note this is just my demo database and will be completely changed when I go live? Thanks for that link @Siva

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i am not wrong SET keyword is required and the extra comma is to be removed..correct me if I am wrong...

```
if($get['cmd'] == 'sname')
{
    mysql_query("update users SET 
    first_name ='$get[first_name]', 
    last_name ='$get[last_name]'
    where id ='$get[id]'") or die(mysql_error());
    //header("Location: $ret"); 
    echo "changes done";
    exit();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a `comma` after the below statement that is not required.

```
`last_name`='$get[last_name]',
```

It should be as stated below. Note that the `comma`  has been removed from the end of this line.

```
`last_name`='$get[last_name]'
```

Comment: Of course. I didn't even think of that. :). Thanks heaps. Goes with answer comment